mvvm application: language changes only after a different UserControl is rendered
It is hard to explain in a few words, I hope wpf mvvm experts can understand the problem and suggest a solution.
In the application window there is a ContentControl binded to the active viewmodel.
Each viewmodel has an associated DataTemplate which specifies the corresponding view (usercontrol). I think it is quite common in a mvvm scenario and there is no need to show the code.
Multi language support is done with resource files and in the usercontrol xaml signs are as the following one:
xmlns:Resources="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Properties"
...
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static Resources:Resources.Hello_label}" />

It works well for usercontrols which are rendered after the language is changed, but I cannot find any way to refresh the displayed one in order to update the signs.
To put in other words: suppose to have some buttons associated to different languages on the same usercontrol of the Hello_label TextBlock. Pushing a button I cannot cause the update of the label. But when a different usercontrol is displayed it reflects the selected language.
How can I solve it ?

"Binding" involves "properties". The binding engine needs an event; like "property changed" to do its thing. You need to bind your TextBlock to a proxy property in your view model that references your "dynamic static" (as you've described it); e.g. ... Text="{Binding TextBlockLabel}" ... public string TextBlockLabel => Resources. Hello_label; .... OnPropertyChanged( nameof( this.TextBlockLabel ) );

@GerrySchmitz
It is how mvvm pattern works. In my viewmodels there are properties and  the "property changed" event for every dynamic field, I don't want to fill the viewmodels with a property for every 'static' sign, I need a different approach.  Maybe, at language change, I can display a wait page which automatically switches back to the original usercontrol, that should work, but I'm looking for something better.

What you're defining as "static" is not static at all.

@GerrySchmitz
I agree, I added multi language support copying it from some example code I found in internet. I think it is not the best way when using mvvm pattern. Can you point me in the right direction suggesting a solution or a valid tutorial ?

The "right direction" is the one that works for you. The problem starts when you make "labels" and "data" separate (for multi-language apps). In this case, "labels" are another form of data. Your language labels, therefore, should come from your model. "Toggling" a language "reloads" all the "label strings"; which could simply be getters using the current language "code". A call to "OnPropertyChanged" (without a property name) would update all the labels (attached to TextBlocks). This works for any app ... if you want to change labels without touching the XAML.
